# Haskell convention: Maybe or empty list?

Tags: haskell

Could any Haskell experts out there please clarify something for me:

Given a simplified example of a function `match` which is supposed to return a matched value from a list, which is the "better" function definition to use `Maybe` or return `[]` (an empty list)?

That is:

```
match :: String -> [String] -> Maybe String
```

or

```
match :: String -> [String] -> [String]     {- possibly empty, if no match -}
```

I prefer the first version for reasons of clarity, but I would be interested to know whether there is a convention for this sort of thing.

Comment: Many thanks for the quick responses. I have accepted luqui's succinct answer.

Comment: If a user wants `[String]` but gets `Maybe String` (or vice-versa), there are the very easy-to-use `maybeToList` and `listToMaybe` natural transformations/monad morphisms to be able to use them together interchangeably.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If it is only ever possible for it to return zero or one matches, then use `Maybe` (because that's what it means); if it is possible to return any number of matches, then use `[]` (because that's what it means).

Comment: +1 perfect answer. Thinking in regex, `List` is to `*` as `Maybe` is to `?`.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use `Maybe String`.  I think it is much more clear. If you think about what you are communicating with the other option, you are saying that your function takes a list and returns either a `String` or a list upon failure.  Semantically that is kind of funky IMO when compared with returning either a `String` or `Nothing`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you state that you return a single matched value if it is present. I would go with the Maybe String, otherwise you would return a list containing a single element, which seems to be odd.